# Separating webdevelopment from webdesign

Tags: php

I'm a student of webdevelopment and I've got a question about the business (after school, finding a job and such).

Now, my college has taught me several things and I've learned several things on my own.
We constantly use XHTML 1.1, CSS 2.1, Javascript (mostly formchecking) and PHP, all our code must be W3C compliant (the online validators), or we don't even get a grade. On my own I've messed around with jQuery a bit and next year we'll be getting ASP.NET and LINQ.
I've also seen MySQL to a decent degree, but I wouldn't consider myself a specialist.

The thing is, while I love coding websites/applications and finding out new stuff and ways to do so, my skills at designing/"making it look pretty" are beyond bad.

What I'm wondering is, in the business, how does this affect job-chances?

I mean, give me a PSD file and the necessary images and I'll give you your working site, no problem. I'll document my code and everything. But to come up with the look&feel on my own... I find it so damn hard to decide which color to use for something, should the hover effect look like this or that, should I have a little arrow appear when I do this, etc etc etc...

Is it expected of a developer to be a designer at the same time? Or do some companies separate it while others don't?

The thing is, I have no experience with companies whatsoever. I have no idea how they implement the creation of their websites. Because as students, we don't get a team of designers who tell us what to make, we have to do everything ourselves. Luckily the dean has already said design won't influence grades.

Comment: I'd rather deal with a developer that understands what can and can't be done in a browser but has no sense of design than a designer who doesn't understand the web cranking out PSDs based on their understanding of print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry about design.  It comes next.  What you do is actually more important; functionality always supercedes visual presence.

I don't believe you will have any troubles finding a job due to lack of design skills.  They'll hire somebody else to whip up the graphics.

I also believe it's common knowledge that the vast majority of good programmers are bad designers.  Hell, just look at the design of [Jon Skeet's web site](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/)!  What more evidence do you need?!

Best regards...

Comment: Myeah, depends on who you're building your site for offcourse. A website that must appeal to a wide public must be a lust for the eye.
A website like Jon's is intended for specialist who seek info, so his visitor's don't give a **** what it looks like.

Answer (score 2):

I would describe you as a Web Developer.

Site layout falls into the graphic design realm. This isn't always the case of course. There are some talented people who are good at both, but they are rare. I would argue these types of people could be masters at either, but not both.

It sounds like you are talented at Web Development. Stick with it. Pick up what you can when it comes to graphic design and site layout. It will help you out when you need to work with a graphic designer.

During an interview for a Software Engineer, if I was asked about graphic design it would raise a red flag.

Answer (score 1):

Some companies separate the careers. I do websites and small desktop application for some advertising agency, and i can't lay out two button that aren't ugly. Usually i team up with a native designer (which can't understand a single line of code, but this is another problem).

But as the time goes on and my experience increases, i feel that i'm learning something, and once or twice i've felt that having both the knowledge of the code and the taste for the design would be really nice.

Answer (score 1):

I work at a small web development firm and when I started I was exactly like you. Not a single idea of how to go about design. Luckily, my job is to get a PSD, and turn it into a website.

Slowly though, I have figured a few things which help with design. You will too, if you keep at it. A few little things learned over time help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Totally dependent on the company. Personally, I'm an absolutely awful designer and I know it. As such, I've only ever worked on jobs (both as an employee and freelance) along with designers. They do exactly as you said, design the site and pass me a PSD, which I slice up and make actually function.

However, I have friends that work at companies where they do both, it just depends on the job. The job posting or the interview should make it clear which way any particular job is going to be, I wouldn't worry too much about it in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're a web developer man, and don't be afraid to be just that. It's really hard to be good at both, and I think a good web developer should be good at all the code stuff, and know their limitations when it comes to design.

You'll find that your skills as a designer will improve over time anyway. As a developer you might never come up with mind blowingly awesomely beautiful designs, but you'll get a sense for what works and what doesn't.

A simple design that works is always better than something that tries too hard and ends up looking like a dog's breakfast.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a definitive answer, so I'll offer an opinion.  It's just hard to give a complete answer to what "some companies do" vs "what others do".

Many companies that work with Silverlight and Windows Presentation Foundation (Microsoft products that I can use as examples) definitely DO separate design from development.  The tools are designed specifically for that purpose, out of a recognition that these skills (design and development) are just different and not all that commonly found in a single individual.  When a company like Microsoft invests in something like this, it probably means that lots of people thought it would be a good idea. (Ok, I know I just set myself up for some differing opinions...)

Your posting sounds like you have concern for your career development.  My suggestion would be that you become excellent at something, or maybe a few very closely related things.  Then let your career get started there and follow your bliss.  The footprint of your skills will grow naturally.

Cheers!
Greg Oliver [MSFT]

Answer (score 1):

There's a corny term going around to describe a web developer who is also a designer: deviner (or diviner).  Here's [a reference](http://www.builderau.com.au/news/soa/Diviner-A-new-role-between-the-developer-and-designer-/0,339028227,339281238,00.htm).

Personally I think that you only need to be a developer and designer if that's the role you put yourself into.  It's going to be required if you are starting your own web service or go to work for a small company that doesn't have the resources to hire a designer.

But really, you can't expect to simply become a designer without putting the same effort into it as you did becoming a developer.  It's not something that you are going to just pick up unless you have a gift for it.  It sounds like you don't.  Neither do I.

I've found that developer types can be good at copying designs though.  If you can find a design that would be a good fit for your development project, you can probably (tastefully and respectfully) copy the basic design or layout.  In fact, you can become quite proficient using this technique without having to have the artistic eye of a real artist.

One thing you don't want to do is spend a great deal of time working on a design when you don't really know what you're doing.  Nothing will stall you faster.  Focus on what you do best; what you can actually deliver effectively and on time.

Answer (score 1):

We once tried to hire a combined graphical wizard and web designer ... we got great people in either category along, but nobody could do both to an adequate degree. The good coders were minimalistic in their designs creating lovely functional sites with logical layout. The other way ... good looking, but total mess.

So don't worry. Web Designer (XHTML, CSS, JavaScript) is fine.